# Rewrite url path to sub domain for API

Tags: .net, api, iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I am using azure traffic manager but my api is on the main simian A record.  However I need a came to take advantage of Azure traffic manager.

My question is can I do GET and POST from the current path to the API to a sub domain like below and if so what is the best approach to do this?

Current API Path

https://test.com/mobile/v1/api/...

New API Path (rewrite?)

https://api.test.com/mobile/v1/api/...

Any performance issues with a solution? I have 500+ apps and can’t manually update the url in each.

Comment: I suggest you to use URL rewrite module. For information about "URL Rewrite 2.0 Performance" , you can refer to this blog: https://blogs.iis.net/danielvl/url-rewrite-2-0-performance

Comment: I'd like to help, but this question is very difficult (for me at least) to understand... `However I need a came to take advantage...` is this a typo?
There shouldn't be a performance issue with doing an IIS-level rewrite in general, but obviously if you have to set up the same rewrite 500+ times that will be a problem. Do you have 500+ app instances, or are there different apps you're rewriting to?

Comment: I dont need to do the same rewrite 500 times.  I am saying 500+ apps use the endpoint https://test.com/mobile/v1/api/... but I want them to use https://api.test.com/mobile/v1/api/... instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well several things here. If you have a wildcard A record, keep in mind you will need a wildcard SSL as well (but thats beside the point).

Your gateway/proxy/load balancer should handle the routing/load balancing for the subdomains just as it would for 'WWW'; after all 'WWW' is just another subdomain.

As for how to setup/config, that is based on the gateway/proxy/load balancer you are using. See the config for 'routing' in the tool you are using.

Comment: I’m using IIS, SSL is fine.

Comment: Mike, IIS is the server. Um... and since I only have knowldge with Open Source (ie Apache, Tomcate, Nginx, etc), here is where I can't help unless you have Nginx or something in front of IIS acting as a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question, you're looking for a scalable solution that allows N number of applications to use the same configuration value for the location of a service.

I would recommend using either service discovery or centralized configuration. The "centralized configuration" is somewhat self-explanatory, and service discovery is where your app knows the name of a service (eg: "the-api") and gets the location from a discovery server at runtime.

If you want to stick with a configuration-based approach, Azure has [a configuration server](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-configuration/) that you could use, or you could use a [Spring Cloud Config Server](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html) and the [Steeltoe client for SCCS](https://docs.steeltoe.io/api/v2/configuration/config-server-provider.html).

If you want to try out the service discovery approach, Steeltoe has options there for [Netflix Eureka](https://docs.steeltoe.io/api/v2/discovery/netflix-eureka.html) and [HashiCorp Consul](https://docs.steeltoe.io/api/v2/discovery/hashicorp-consul.html)

Comment: That is not it.